# No display - ListView using SimpleAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, adapter

I'm trying to display a list of ALL the wifi AP's in range i.e. including those with same SSID's as these are not shown in the default wifi settings.

This is my first attempt at Android SDK and I've gotten so far:

```
package com.iiitd.wifistats;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class WiFiStats extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    WifiManager wifi;
    List<ScanResult> scanResults;
    ArrayList<Map<String, Integer>> list;
    SimpleAdapter adapter;
    ListView listview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (!wifi.isWifiEnabled()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Turning on WiFi...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }

        carryON();
    }

    private void carryON(){
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonScan);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                wifi = (WifiManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                scanResults = wifi.getScanResults();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Scanning...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                list = buildData(scanResults);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), list.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                adapter = new SimpleAdapter(v.getContext(), list, R.layout.listitem, new String[]{"BSSID", "strength"}, new int[] {R.id.BSSID, R.id.strength});
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), adapter.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }

    private ArrayList<Map<String, Integer>> buildData(java.util.List<ScanResult> s) {
        ArrayList<Map<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Integer>>();
        for (ScanResult result : s) {
            list.add(putData(result.BSSID, result.level));
        }
        return list;
    }

    private HashMap<String, Integer> putData(String BSSID, int level) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> item = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        item.put(BSSID, level);
        return item;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.wi_fi_stats, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}
```

This is my activity_xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Scan"
            android:id="@+id/buttonScan"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_above="@+id/buttonScan"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is listitem.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                android:padding="6dip">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/strength"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="26dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/BSSID"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/strength"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Example application"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**There is no list displayed when the I start a scan. However, if I use a toast, the I can see that the list is forming correctly.** Can someone guide me here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the code here

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(v.getContext(), list, R.layout.listitem, new String[]{"BSSID", "strength"}, new int[] {R.id.BSSID, R.id.strength});
```

The String array is telling the adapter the keys to be used when accessing the map that you define. In your code, you are assigning the values as such

```
private HashMap<String, Integer> putData(String BSSID, int level) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> item = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    item.put(BSSID, level);
    return item;
}
```

This is assigning the int for level to the key set by the String BSSID. You need to change all occurrences of HashMap in your code to take a String value and a String key `HashMap< String, String >`and replace the method with the following

```
private HashMap<String, String> putData(String BSSID, int level) {
    HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
    item.put("BSSID", BSSID);
    item.put("strength", Integer.toString(level));
    return item;
}
```

Comment: Okay. I tried that and it seems to works! :)
However, the values are not getting updated every time I press 'Scan'. Infact, only one pair of values are being preserved across several application runs. I think I need to flush the listview contents every time 'Scan' is pressed. How can I do that?

Comment: After you have changed the contents of an adapter, you can call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); and it should alert the adapter that the views need to be refreshed.

Comment: Yes, I tried that.                 
                listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
Didn't work.

Comment: Strange,  you might try instantiating the list and the adapter in the onCreate () and assigning the adapter to the ListView. Then,  rather then creating a new list in buildList, call the lists clear method. Also, try and assign your class variables in the onCreate and use the onClick() method to update the data.

Comment: Okay, I think I've narrowed down the problem - the scanResults are themselves not being updated! The startScan() method should initiate a new scan, but even after 2,3 or 5 mins, the scanResults don't get updated.

Even starting a manual scan via Settings->WiFi->Scan, does not update the AP's. Infact, I turned off my router and it was still showing up in Androids default AP chooser!

The only way I got the list to update was to toggle WiFi. Any idea what kind of sorcery is this? :P

Comment: It seems the getScanResults () method returns the results of the last successful scan and does not perform a new one. The method startScan () requests a new scan and returns a Boolean whether it was successful.

Comment: I'm checking for the return variable to be false. It always returns true.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/android-developers/D3ItX5DPrmk check this article out. It discusses how to scan and get the results with a BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried extending ListActivity instead of a plain activity? you could need to change the ID of the ListView in your XML to android:id="@id/android:list"

Then in your caryON() method you would call `setListAdapter(adapter);` after initialising the new Simple Adapter

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(v.getContext(), list, R.layout.listitem, new String[]{"BSSID", "strength"}, new int[] {R.id.BSSID, R.id.strength});
setListAdapter(adapter);
```